# OpenCV 3.0 - error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor

Tags: c++, opencv, file-io, opencv3.0

I have simple OpenCV code that I am using to load an image and convert it to grayscale.  I have a folder with images that I have replicated.  It's just the same frame over and over again with different file names, the content of the files are exactly the same.

I run a loop and try to convert the images and it runs for 1020 frames and stops on that specific frame every time with the error:

> "error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor"

popping up every time.  I don't understand this, if the code works for the first image, in theory it should work for all the other images in the folder as they are the same file just with different file names.  I am running OpenCV 3.0 and also receive the specific error that says:

> "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor,file/home/blah/OpenCV3.0/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7453"

when the program stops.

My code is:

```
char * baseImagePath; //these are updated as the program iterates
char * nextImagePath; //they contain the full path of the image

Mat baseImage, nextImage;
Mat grayImage1,grayImage2;

baseImage = imread(baseImagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

if(baseImage.empty()){

    printf("%s EMPTY!\n", baseImagePath);

}

cvtColor(baseImage, grayImage1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

nextImage = imread(nextImagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

if(nextImage.empty()){

    printf("%s EMPTY!\n", nextImagePath);

}

cvtColor(nextImage, grayImage2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

So, this is very odd.  When I run my code, I confirm that my program thinks the image at a specific frame is empty, but when I run:

```
display frame.jpg
```

were frame.jpg is the frame that my program claims is empty, imageMagick displays the video just fine.

Comment: Looks like some file in the folder is not a valid image or it's already a grey-scale image. Try to check all the files and make sure all of them are colored images (RGB or RGBA).

Comment: What do you mean by a valid image?  The images that I use is just one image, replicated over and over again.  It's just the same file content with a different file name.  The image I use is definitely a color image.

Comment: I mean, since you are replicating the image (and I imagine, you are using some loop to go through all of them) maybe the loop (or whatever you are using) is reading some unexpected file that's not a valid image. You say that it stops on a specific frame, is this frame equal to the others or it has  some difference? you could try to use commands like file, identify to see wither if this file is a valid image and if it has the same md5sum as the others (just to make sure it's a copy of the original image).

Comment: Check that the images are loaded correctly, try to imshow them

Comment: I did what you said and verified that they are valid files.  There is still the same error.  Just to be sure, I took a video from YouTube and used avconv to convert the video into frames and it still gives me the same error, just on a different frame now, frame 1038.  Am I doing something wrong?  Instead of imshow, I just use display (ImageMagick) and the image opens up fine.

Comment: I also verified that the image is valid and it is not a grayscale image as well, it is a color image taken from the YouTube video with avconv.

Comment: 1) The image path is wrong and you're not loading any image or 2) it's not 3 channel. No other options..

Comment: You were right!  I ran a simple C program and confirmed that I had too many open files using errno - does imread close the file after opening it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the OpenCV code, but with the C code I was using to iterate through the files.  I had too many files open and that caused the program to fail. This was confirmed with the errno code I received upon program termination.